# S3 change last modified date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, events, amazon-sqs

I have an S3 bucket that sends event notifications for new objects to SQS. Event notifications are filtered to one folder.
I want to simulate an upload of a large number of files at the same time. The problem is I need to upload faster. The fastest I got was to upload to another folder in the same s3 bucket and move the folder into the one with the trigger. It still copies files one by one.
Another thing I tried is:

- disable event notification
- copy files into the target folder
- enable event notification
- copy each file into itself (which causes the last modified date change and triggers an event notification)

Is there something faster? Or can we change the last modified date and trigger an event notification without copying?

I'm aware I can generate SQS events programmatically, but I want to do some real testing.

Comment: A self-copy is the fastest way imho.

Comment: Did you investigate multi-threaded or multi-process uploads? Maybe from a small cluster of EC2 instances in the same S3 region.

Comment: @luk2302 it does not distinguish self-copy as a special case unfortunately.

Comment: @jarmod that'll work I suppose.